# Does setting a theme in my Android App take care of memory leaks?

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, app-themes, android-theme

I'm working on an app with a lot of activities, and each activity uses the same background. It appears that having one background set to multiple activities will cause that background image to be allocated to multiple memory blocks. In order to efficiently manage the phone's memory, I've been reading up on Google's dev site on how to avoid memory leaks where some coded solutions are suggested, but it would be tedious to have to manage the memory on so many occasions. As an alternate solution, I'm considered using a theme for the application where the background is set for each view, but I don't know if that solves the memory management problem.

If I used a theme to set the background image instead of setting the background image to each activity, will the device automatically manage the memory for me?

Comment: My personal policy is let the OS do as much as it can, because it will probably do it more cleanly. Theming seems like a solid choice.

Comment: Please provide more details as to how you are using the background. Some questions to answer would be: Is the image used directly in the layout via the ID? Is the image being loaded as a bitmap? Are you creating image views and holding onto a contact?

Comment: I don't think it will.  I'm currently tracking an issue related to memory issues with a large background image that is set via a theme applied to the entire application.